# C# @ modifier for methods parameters

Tags: c#, resharper

I was using ReSharper plugin on VS2010 and i was generating an interface method.
ReSharper put an @ on the parameter name. WHat is that used for?

```
int Count(Func<ContratoList, bool> @where);
```

Whats the difference for

```
int Count(Func<ContratoList, bool> where);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this posting about the `@` verbatim operator http://sanity-free.org/112/all_about_the_sign_csharp_verbatim_identifier.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `@` symbol allows you to use [reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) in a variable name.

```
int @class = 1;

void MyMethod(int @goto);

bool @public { get; set; }
```

As Marc correctly pointed out in his comment and his answer, ReSharper is actually wrong to do this because `where` is a [Contextual Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx) and is not actually a reserved word, so your method will compile without the `@`.

Comment: `where` ***is explicitly not*** a *reserved* keyword; it is a *contextual* keyword. This means that in effect, the `@where` in the question achieves: exactly nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It does say that in the link I included in the answer, but I assumed it to be the same with `where` because of the question. I've upvoted your answer though, well spotted!

Comment: Resharper is overzealous with adding @ to things.

Answer (score 26):

In many ways, resharper is wrong to do this. `where` is a *contextual* keyword, meaning: it only acts as a keyword in some very specific scenarios (i.e. LINQ). In the position indicated, it actually does nothing. It would not be confused as a keyword there, as when the C# language designers add keywords to C# they need to ensure pre-existing code continues to compile (as far as possible), and that would have been legal in earlier C#.

The usage of `@` also confuses/complicates some tools (razor, in particular, since razor already uses `@` to indicate the start of code - meaning that for a variable using `@` (i.e. `@string`) sometimes you need `@` and sometimes you need `@@` - and I know of at least one false-positive IDE warning this can cause).

However! If the parameter was `if` or `class` etc, then `@if` / `@class` allows you to use that as a variable name rather than getting confused as a C# keyword. That *also* isn't a great idea, note. But by the same token, we wouldn't start doing that to *all* our code (`string @name = ...` etc) - so why do it here? It isn't needed, and **as demonstrated by this question**, it has added confusion.

Personally, though, I'd find a parameter name that isn't a keyword or contextual-keyword.

Comment: It may also be worth adding that `where` is not only a LINQ keyword, but also used for generic type constraints

Comment: Yes, designers are trying to ensure that existing code doesn't break as far as possible. However, I was quite surprised when one Monday morning the module that no one touched for a couple of months suddenly refused to build. Turns out, it used `async` as a method parameter name. Morale: don't install Async CTP before going on week end

Answer (score 4):

It allows you to use reserved keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 4):

It will stop this parameter acting like a keyword (as `where`is a keyword in linq amongst other things).

Comment: It would not act as a keyword in that position.

Comment: @Marc - that's a good point. It must just be applying it as a general rule - trying to do it perfectly by context would be more of a challenge I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This is done because 'where' is a protected keyword in C# (LINQ)

Answer (score 1):

it allows you to use reserved words as params.